# jQuery - Loop through styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `click` event that is bound to a `div`

```
bind('click', function() {
var styles = $(this).attr('style').split(';');
$.each(styles, function(i) {
    var style = this.split(':');
    alert(style[0]);
    if(style[0] == 'font-size'){
        $('#controls #font-size option[value="'+style[1]+'"]').attr('selected', true);
    } else if(style[0] == 'color'){
        $('#controls #color option[value="'+style[1]+'"]').attr('selected', true);
    } else if(style[0] == 'text-align'){
        $('#controls #text-align option[value="'+style[1]+'"]').attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

The `alert()` will alert the style, ie font-size, color, width, etc.., but when it comes to the `if` statement it does not go into that code.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: check with toLower() and trim()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably white space between your style, try in you if to pass this condition :

```
$.trim(style[0]) == 'font-size'
```

Comment: ahhhhh! Thank you! This was driving me nutty!